# wso2esb custom mediator class cast exception

Tags: java, maven, wso2, wso2-esb

I have written a custom class mediator, but I am have trouble deploying it in my esb when I compile my code using the maven shade plugin. I need to compile my mediator class in a jar containing all of its dependencies. Here is the stack trace for the error:

```
  [2015-11-09 10:01:28,088] ERROR - ClassMediatorFactory Error : com.solers.espds.util.messaging.mediators.FastTrackMediator
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.test.FastTrackMediator cannot be cast to org.apache.synapse.Mediator
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ClassMediatorFactory.createSpecificMediator(ClassMediatorFactory.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractMediatorFactory.createMediator(AbstractMediatorFactory.java:91)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MediatorFactoryFinder.getMediator(MediatorFactoryFinder.java:223)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.AbstractListMediatorFactory.addChildren(AbstractListMediatorFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SequenceMediatorFactory.createAnonymousSequence(SequenceMediatorFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.ProxyServiceFactory.createProxy(ProxyServiceFactory.java:178)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.SynapseXMLConfigurationFactory.defineProxy(SynapseXMLConfigurationFactory.java:142)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder.createProxyServices(MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder.java:239)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.xml.MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder.java:132)
    at org.apache.synapse.config.SynapseConfigurationBuilder.getConfiguration(SynapseConfigurationBuilder.java:100)
    at org.apache.synapse.Axis2SynapseController.createSynapseConfiguration(Axis2SynapseController.java:479)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.CarbonSynapseController.createSynapseConfiguration(CarbonSynapseController.java:169)
    at org.apache.synapse.ServerManager.start(ServerManager.java:177)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.initESB(ServiceBusInitializer.java:424)
    at org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.ServiceBusInitializer.activate(ServiceBusInitializer.java:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerHandler.startEventBroker(EventBrokerHandler.java:58)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.core.internal.builder.EventBrokerBuilderDS.activate(EventBrokerBuilderDS.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:451)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.initializeCarbon(CarbonServerManager.java:517)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager.start(CarbonServerManager.java:219)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreServiceComponent.activate(CarbonCoreServiceComponent.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.getEligible(Resolver.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.serviceChanged(SCRManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.registerHttpService(Activator.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.Activator.addProxyServlet(Activator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.init(ProxyServlet.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.init(DelegationServlet.java:38)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1267)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is my class:

```
import org.apache.synapse.ManagedLifecycle;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.core.SynapseEnvironment;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class FastTrackMediator extends AbstractMediator implements ManagedLifecycle {
    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
        log.info("Hello, world!");

        return true;
    }

    public void init(SynapseEnvironment synapseEnvironment) {

    }

    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>fast-track-mediator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Fast Track Mediator</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <releases>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </releases>
            <id>wso2-nexus</id>
            <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
            <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                         <configuration>
                            <relocations>
                               <relocation>
                                 <pattern>org.apache.synapse</pattern>
                                 <shadedPattern>org.apache.synapse.shaded</shadedPattern>
                               </relocation>
                             </relocations>
                             <artifactSet>
                               <excludes>

                                 <exclude>net.sf.saxon:*</exclude>
                               </excludes>

                             </artifactSet>
                           </configuration>

                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>uber-${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.synapse</groupId>
                <artifactId>synapse-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.2-wso2v4</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

I imagine this error is a result of OSGI loading certain classes twice, but I cannot figure out how to fix the problem. Thanks

Comment: Try to exclude synapse dependencies from your shaded jar. This is probably the reason you're getting the class cast exception.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce your issue. but couldn't. it is properly build for me and generate jar file. i suspect issue is with your environment. follow bellow steps and see.

Use WSO2 Developer studio 3.8
(better try this on new workspace)

1. Create new Maven Multi module project.
2. Create new ESB config project inside multi module project
3. create empty sequence in side the project (just to detect to deploy)
4. Create new mediator project inside multi module project
5. create your class and implement as you did.
6. create new composite Application project on same workspace and select your both projects to that composite project

Now you are done.

now go to same place where maven multi module project pom file exist from your command prompt

```
mvn clean install
```

you can see its build without error.

maven multimodule pom (auto generated)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.krishantha.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>MavenParentProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>MavenParentProject</name>
  <description>MavenParentProject</description>
  <modules>
    <module>MediatorSampleProject</module>
    <module>SampleMediator</module>
  </modules>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.9</version>
        <configuration>
          <buildcommands />
          <projectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.wso2.developerstudio.eclipse.mavenmultimodule.project.nature</projectnature>
          </projectnatures>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

class mediator code:

```
package com.wso2;

import org.apache.synapse.ManagedLifecycle;
import org.apache.synapse.MessageContext;
import org.apache.synapse.core.SynapseEnvironment;
import org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractMediator;

public class FastTrackMediator extends AbstractMediator implements ManagedLifecycle { 

    public boolean mediate(MessageContext messageContext) {
        log.info("Hello, world!");

        return true;
    }

    public void init(SynapseEnvironment synapseEnvironment) {

    }

    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

jar file created

```
Krishanthas-MacBook-Pro:MavenParentProject krishantha$ find . -iname *.jar 
./SampleMediator/target/SampleMediator-1.0.0.jar
Krishanthas-MacBook-Pro:MavenParentProject krishantha$
```

project structure should look like this
[image]

Comment: The jar builds correctly for me as well, but runtime errors appear due to a class cast exception when I include synapse dependencies in my generated jar. I suppose I will have to leave the dependencies out.

Comment: is there any specific requirement to add synapse dependencies to your jar?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are copying the jar to `MI-HOME/lib` folder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).